# How do I unpack/unzip a "(.TRS/PACK) TERSE compressed data (PACK, V) (2000/1)" file?

Tags: zip, compression, zlib, pack, pak

The files have a custom file extension that was obviously made by the program creator, but a file-type check returned "100.0% (.TRS/PACK) TERSE compressed data (PACK, V) (2000/1)" as the file-type.

The unpacked files should be primarily images, probably .PNG. I cannot share the files.

I tried using unpack200 and got "Corrupted pack file: magic/ver = 02010452/111.111 should be CAFED00D/150.7 OR CAFED00D/160.1 OR CAFED00D/170.1 OR CAFED00D/171.0".